# How can i open contact detail screen in iOS from my app in React native

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

I would like to open contact detail screen from my app when user performs an action like pushes a button . I have searched a lot but couldn't find an answer.

[here is the screen im talking about, Ignore the red box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJZBU.jpg)

Im on RN 0.38.1 and React 15.4.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iOS' Phone app does not provide mechanism to open screens or interact with its portions in any way.

Alternative solution - access contact list a recreate contact library on your own.